# Jquery Добавить и удалить класс

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я хочу добавить новый класс в  и удалить существующий  при нажатии с помощью Jquery. Проблема заключается в том что нажимая на данный див ничего не происходит(В новом классе заданы другие свойства для данного дива)

```js
$('#navbar').on('click',function(){
  $('#navbar').removeClass('navbar');
  $('#navbar').addClass('ShowMenu');
})
```

```css
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 0px;
    


}
.navbar:hover{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
}

.ShowMenu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.ShowMenu .list-element{
    
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FCA311;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px black;
    
}

.ShowMenu .list-element:hover{
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ShowMenu .close{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: red;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 0% 20%, 30% 50%, 0% 80%, 20% 100%, 50% 70%, 80% 100%, 100% 80%, 70% 50%, 100% 20%, 80% 0%, 50% 30%);


}

.ShowMenu .close:hover{
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.2em;
}
.ShowMenu .menu_title{
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0A1428;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
    text-align: center;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
  <div class="close"></div>
  <div class="menu_title">Menu</div>
  <ul class="navbar_list">
    <li class="list-element">Introduction Video</li>
    <li class="list-element">About us</li>
    <li class="list-element">Our Projects</li>
    <li class="list-element">Our Services</li>
    <li class="list-element">Contact with us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Код рабочий вполне....может ты просто динамически html добавляешь

Comment: Кстати раз уж пользуетесь jQuery, то для таких задач там есть метод [switchClass](https://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/)

Comment: Можете по подробнее. В чем проблема я так и не понял.Код и в правду работает здесь,но на моем сайте он не работает. Расскажите по подробнее в чем проблема

Comment: @EzioMercer это jqueryUI

Comment: @DanilMaltsev ты html добавляешь как? динамически?

Comment: То что я порекомндовал, не значит, что ваш код неправильный :) Я просто предложил более короткий вариант) Проблема в том, что у вас очень многовероятно, что jQuery тупо не находит нужный вам элемент. В большинстве случаев это связано с тем, что вы обращаетесь к элементу, до того как он появился в DOM-е, а это значит, что вы создаёте элемент с помощью JS (jQuery) и потом вставляете в DOM. Самый простой способ - это сохранить при создании элемент в переменную и потом обращаться к ней. Ну или 100% быть уверенным, что вы обращаетесь к элементу ТОЛЬКО после того как вставили его на страницу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А, точно, спасибо)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Стыдно признаться не знаю что такое добавление HTML динамически. Буду очень благодарен если объясните мне разницу и может быть это поможет решить проблему:)

Comment: @DanilMaltsev у вас `<div class="navbar" id="navbar">` в вёрстке прописано или создаётся с помощью jQuery?

Comment: @EzioMercer В верстке прописано

Comment: А что выводит в консоль это `$('#navbar')`?

Comment: @EzioMercer ничего